# How to build a form to edit foreign key attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have got a model `Member`, which has a foreign key to model `Profile` (which is a very simple model, it's just `text: string`).

I've got `members` controller. In `members/edit` , I would like to edit the member's profile `text` field. How can I create a form to do so?

```
<%= form_for @profile do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :text %><br/>
      <%= f.text_area :text %><br/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.submit 'Save Profile' %>
    </p>

<% end %>
```

The above obviously does no work, neither `<%= form_for @member do |f| %>` I guess. Any ideas? Because I do not want to update all `Member` attributes, just this one attribute which is actually a row from another table.

Comment: There is not alot of context here (no Controller code at all) but `@member = Member.find(params[:id]);@profile = Profle.find_or_initialize_by(member_id: @member.id)` should do the trick then you can use `form_for @profile`

Comment: @engineersmnky I can't find a profile by searching for a member_id because member_id is not an attribute of Profile. But profile_id is an attribute of member, understand?

Comment: so a member belongs_to a profile? That seems like a strange implementation and particular reason you went that route? I am assuming this is a one-to-one relationship

Comment: Actually , one member has one profile  @engineersmnky

Comment: Not the way you have it right now a member belongs to a profile thus the profile_id. This field shows ownership the profile owns the member because it has stamped it's id on it. A profile would then have one member. I think you might have just implemented this backwords.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, an association must exist between Member and Profile model... If each member has only one profile go with has_one association. If each member has many profiles then go with has_many association.

```
Class Member < ActiveRecord :: Base
  has_many/one :profiles
end
Class Profile < ActiveRecord :: Base
  belongs_to :member
end
```

In your profile migrations, add the below code:

```
t.belongs_to :member
```

Now, add in your Members controller, show action:

```
def edit
  @member = Member.find(params[:id])
  @profile = @member.profiles.build
             @member.build_profile       # for has_one association
end
```

Comment: Note the OP's comment where a member belongs to a profile. Also I don't think `show` is the right place for this

Comment: if member has the profile and the user wants to edit the profile when he is in member's page, then show is the right area.... It depends on the criteria

Comment: the OP stated he is in `members/edit` so this sounds more like a `fields_for` usage

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure in your models you have setup the belongs_to and has_one relationships appropriately.  Then make sure in your routes you have nested the two so that it recognizes the associated tables attributes you're updating:

```
 resources :member do
        resources :profile
      end
```

Then your form should refer to both tables like so:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@member, @profile], html: {class: "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
     <%= f.input :ATTRIBUTE_HERE, required: false, label: "Edit Answer:" %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Note the OP's comment where a member belongs to a profile